# Как настроить Android-приложение для доступа к Facebook API?

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

Создал Android-приложение, прописал ключи, указал имя пакета, класса, указал идентификатор приложения в создаваемом приложении. В итоге постоянно получаю сообщение:

> Приложение не настроено: Разработчики настоящего приложения не настроили это приложение для входа на Facebook.

Что я делаю не так? Пробовал новое приложение создавать, проверял хэши всеми доступными способами, а он ни в какую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё решилось очень просто. Приложение не было доступно для использования, только я как разработчик имел к нему доступ. Но чтобы сделать его доступным, обязательно заполните поле Settings->Contact Email. Таким образом приложение стало доступно не разработчику. ))

Answer (score 4):

Сам сейчас столкнулся с этой проблемой.

Решилось всё быстро:
Открываем настройки приложения на facebook.
Заходим в раздел Settings.
Указываем валидный Contact Email.
Переходим в Status&Review и переключаем кнопку возле надписи "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?" в положение "YES".

Answer (score 0):

Warning
Приложение не настроено: Это приложение все еще в режиме разработки, и у вас нет к нему доступа. Переключитесь на зарегистрированный аккаунт тестового пользователя или попросите администратора предоставить вам разрешения.